# Cannot Explicitly Load Navigation Properties with Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am upgrading a .NET Core 2.2 project to .NET Core 3.1 using Entity Framework Core. I am having some issues trying to use explicit loading of navigation properties. I can pass a string to the `.Collection()` or `.Reference()` methods, but everything [I see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit) for explicit loading uses lambda expressions. I have not been able to find a package that would give me the lambda version of this method.

Code that builds:

```
var item = _dbContext.Users.First();
var entry = _dbContext.Entry(item).Collection("Address");
```

Code that won't build:

```
var item = _dbContext.Users.First();
var entry = _dbContext.Entry(item).Collection(x => x.Address);
```

Message in VS Code for the code that won't build

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type [RH.Api] *csharp(CS1660)*

User Model

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public UserStatus? Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Address Model

```
public class Address
{
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message you received? Can you show us your model?

Comment: @mj1313 Updated description to include the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. My solution is not using `DbContext` directly, but through inheritance and an interface. So `Entry()` was overridden, and I didn't catch it was only returning `EntityEntry` instead of `EntityEntry<TEntity>`. Modifying the override fixed my issue.

Old:

```
public interface IDbContext : IDisposable
{
    EntityEntry Entry(object entity);
}

public class MyDbContext: DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public override EntityEntry Entry(object entity)
    {
        return base.Entry(entity);
    }
}
```

New:

```
public interface IDbContext : IDisposable
{
    EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
}

public class MyDbContext: DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public override EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Entry(entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Address` is not a collection type, changing your code to

```cs
var entry = _dbContext
    .Entry(item)
    .Reference(x => x.Address)
    .Load();
```

To make sense of the error message (`Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type [RH.Api] csharp(CS1660)`) take a look at the method signature of the `Collection` method overloads:

- `Collection<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity,IEnumerable<TProperty>>>)`
- `Collection(String)`

The expression `x => x.Address` does not return an `IEnumerable<T>` so the compiler tries to convert the expression to `string` and fails.

Comment: This was not the issue, I didn't get lambda option with `.Reference()` or with `.Collection()`